# Complete set of 2004 Knights Kingdom card images?

Tags: piece-information, castle

Back in 2004 LEGO released a Knights Kingdom line of sets with trading cards for a trading card game. Those trading cards had some pictures and story information on them.

[image: example images]

I was able to find pictures of most of them on BrickLink, but cards [50](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=kkc50), [55](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=kkc55), [62](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=kkc62), [67](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=kkc67), and [76](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=kkc76) do not have images (although I did find a picture of 76, shown above).

Is there anywhere I can find a complete set of images, or at-least the images not available on BrickLink?

Answer (score 2):

Card 62 (Gargoyles) can be found near the bottom of this page: http://www.mikerayhawk.com/knights_kingdom.htm